# AutoCompleteBox for WinRT (C# and XAML) - Selecting item list using arrow keys

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I have Used an Auto Complete Box for my Windows Store App Project.

when I type something the suggestion list will appear but I cannot select the Item that I want using the arrow keys of the keyboard.

Because of this issue the application is not user friendly..
I need a solution to overcome this issue

this is the link of github

https://github.com/igorkulman/AutoCompleteBox

Comment: You can handle the key down event in your application to select items in list

Comment: I tried. It is not possible... If you know the way please explain

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recomend Syncfusion controls for WinRT Xaml

You can make use of SfTextBoxExt control that have the keyboard navigation support.

Please go through the following link for more details,
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/text-box-ext